# aws Glue: Does Glue offer a way to query items with condition in dynamodb

Tags: aws-glue, dynamodb-queries

tried below code,but its not working

```html
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={"dynamodb.input.tableName": "xyz",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id = 2"
    }
   )
```